# Sending argument in reverse_lazy django - Python

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using reverse_lazy as following

```
def index:
    if firstTimeLogin == 0:

        response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('abc', args={'cid': 0}))
    else:

        response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('abc', args={'cid': 1}))
```

abc view

```
def abc(request, userid = None, cid =1 ):
    return HttpResponse(cid)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^abc/$', views.abc, name='abc'),
url(r'^abc/(?P<userid>.*)/$', views.abc, name='abc'),
url(r'^abc/(?P<cid>.*)/$', views.abc, name='abc'),
```

Now when I get redirected to def abc through reverse_lazy I get url like:
`baseurl/appname/abc/cid`, Here I dont know how I can fetch value of cid.

Please correct if the some other approach is required. I just need to pass some argument to reverse_lazy which I want to fetch in `def abc`

**update**

Refering what romaan is saying:
I have updated:
**urls.py as:**

```
url(r'^abc/(?P<cid>.*)/$', views.abc, name='abcfirst')
```

and 
**redirect as:**

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('abcfirst', args={'cid': 1}))
```

still I am unable to access arguments I am sending through reverse_lazy.

Comment: `name` that you give should identify the URL route rather than the view. Hence preferable to use different names in url and avoid any confusion

Answer (score 3):

You have two urls that have the same name, and take in the same parameters (same regex).

You can't combine these two to have the view take in both, thats not how django works.

You either have to

- Make a url that takes in two parameters
- Make separate views

But either way, you can't use the same name for different urls.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `args` with `kwargs` in parameters of `reverse_lazy` function:

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('abcfirst', kwargs={'cid': 1}))
```